# Compiling C programs while including .h files in gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I have to write a program that has external C files. I originally wrote this program in Visual Studio, but I must now switch to `gcc` on Linux. I included the `.h` file that allows me to call a function in another C file. This works in Visual Studio, but gcc doesn't accept the reference. It breaks when trying to call the function `convertAllStrings(c,size)`.

The error is: `` undefined reference to `convertAllStrings' ``

I searched around on Google, and found some people with this issue who said I should use the `gcc -I` command. I tried this but no luck. Specifically I used:

```
gcc -I/home/CS/user/unix Main.c -o proj
```

I have `Main.C`, `convertAll.h`, and `convertAll.c` in the same directory. Here is my code:

File Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "convertAll.h"

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int size;
    char strings[100];
    char temp;

    printf("Number of Strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    char **c = malloc(size);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        printf("Enter string %i ",(i+1));
        scanf("%c", &temp); // temp statement to clear buffer
        fgets(strings, 100, stdin);
        c[i] = malloc(strlen(strings) + 1);
        strcpy(c[i], strings);
        i++;
    }    

    convertAllStrings(c,size); // ** CODE BREAKS HERE

    return 0;
}
```

File convertAll.h:

```
#ifndef convertAll_H_
#define convertAll_H_

void convertAllStrings(char **sentenceList, int numOfSentences);

#endif
```

File convertAll.c:

```
void convertAllStrings(char **sentenceList, int numOfSentences){

    printf("function pass 0 is: %s\n", sentenceList[0]);

}
```

Comment: This appears to be a linking error, not a compiling error. Did you link both object files to create your executable?

Comment: You should `#include "convertAll.h"` in `convertAll.c` so you get the benefit of cross-checking.  You also need to `#include <stdio.h>`, of course.

Comment: `char **c = malloc(size);` This will be too small. You'll need `char **c = malloc(size * sizeof *c);`

Comment: try: gcc -I/home/CS/user/unix Main.c convertAll.o -o proj

Comment: Learn to use some builder automation tool like GNU `make`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used:

```
gcc -I/home/CS/user/unix Main.c -o proj
```

You are only compiling Main.c here. You haven't compiled convertAll.c.

You need:

```
gcc -I/home/CS/user/unix Main.c convertAll.c -o proj
```

or you could probably use one of these:

```
gcc -I. Main.c convertAll.c -o proj
gcc     Main.c convertAll.c -o proj
```

(BTW, you'll better [ask the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) for all warnings and debug info with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't do the job:

```
gcc -I/home/CS/user/unix Main.c -o proj
```

That tries to compile and link `main.c` into `proj`

I.E it does not even use the convertAll.c file.

Suggest something like the following:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 Main.c -o Main.o  -I.
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11 convertAll.c -o convertAll.o -I.
gcc Main.o convertAll.o -o proj
```

The visual studio did this for you, because you included the files in the project.

You could write a `Makefile` that does all this,then execute it with

```
make
```

then exec your program with

```
./proj
```

The following would be a suitable Makefile for your project.

```
SHELL  := /bin/sh

NAME   := proj


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)  # or perhaps INC := convertAll.h

MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

LDFLAGS := 

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11

LIBS    :=   

.PHONY: all
all : $(NAME)


#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #


#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========


# 
# compile the .c files into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 


.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========


# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

Note: indented lines must be proceeded by a `<tab>` char

Comment: @melpomene,  While it 'may' be redundant, it does tell `make` where to find the 'home grown' header files.    I see it as 'good practice' so it will not be forgotten when working with more complex projects

Comment: It tells `make` nothing. `make` doesn't look inside your build rules.